# Ionic 2 ion-searchbar showCancelButton not working in Android

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic2.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3 Build version 8E162
```

I cannot get the [`ion-searchbar`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/) to display the cancel using `showCancelButton` button on the Android platform.

```
  <ion-searchbar  [showCancelButton]="true" class="ion-searchtext" id="ion-searchtext" [(ngModel)]="searchQueryText" (change)="onChangeText($event)" (ionClear)="onCancelText($event)" (ionInput)="onInputText($event)" placeholder="Keyword Search" debounce="1"></ion-searchbar>
```

**iOS**

[image]

**Android**

[image]

The same issue is reported [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8403), but it doesn't appear to be resolved yet, and was wondering if anyone has a work around?

Thanks

Comment: can you start typing in android version. it should show then.. check the demo in the docs..http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/

Comment: Is this what you mean:  $ android version
The android command is no longer available.

Comment: no.. in the android search bar start typing... it shows up the `X` icon

Comment: Yes, the `X` shows up, but the `showCancelButton` attribute does not work.

Comment: isnt that for cancelling the text? I believe that is the cancel button for android

Comment: This X button shows up on Android and iOS when showCancelButton is false. When set to true, on iOS is effected.   I don't agree that Android should not display cancel text.

Comment: ah.. ok my bad.

Comment: The cancel button is the back arrow on the left on android

Comment: apologies @Suraj. You were correct, no button for Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cancel button is the back arrow icon on the left of the input field, it is quite confusing and got me initially as well, here is demo I have created where you can see it working:

```
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-searchbar
      [(ngModel)]="searchString" 
      [showCancelButton]="showSearchCancelButton"
      (ionInput)="searchStuff(searchString)"
      (ionCancel)="onCancelSearch()">
    </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

component:

```
  ...
  onCancelSearch(): void {
    alert('cancel clicked');
  }
  ...
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/O04i7clYW0ktmxQO1Rrl?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

There's no "CancelButton" on Android.

You can check it by yourself on : [searchbar.ts](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/41e34fc4ce08444330d0c7781c367dce1e6ee0a1/src/components/searchbar/searchbar.ts) on the official repository.

```
  /**
   * @hidden
   * Show the iOS Cancel button on focus, hide it offscreen otherwise
   */
  positionCancelButton() {
    if (!this._cancelButton || !this._cancelButton.nativeElement) {
      return;
    }
    let showShowCancel = this._sbHasFocus;
    if (showShowCancel !== this._isCancelVisible) {
      let cancelStyleEle = this._cancelButton.nativeElement;
      let cancelStyle = cancelStyleEle.style;
      this._isCancelVisible = showShowCancel;
      if (showShowCancel) {
        cancelStyle.marginRight = '0';
      } else {
        let offset = cancelStyleEle.offsetWidth;
        if (offset > 0) {
          cancelStyle.marginRight = -offset + 'px';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Android and IOS are not similar.

Comment: As @Und3rTow said, The cancel button is the back arrow on the left on android.